# Kubernetes API for the cluster in AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to list all the workloads/deployments we're running on the clusters we're running on AKS. I don't see an endpoint for this in [AKS API REST reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/), how do I get the deployments etc?

Comment: are you talking about k8s API service accessing from inside k8s?

Comment: Hi, no I'm simply trying to query the endpoint using Postman. I'm no API person and certainly not a k8s one so all of this is quite alien to me.

Answer (score 1):

AKS API is for managing clusters.

See [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) if you want to access anything *within* a cluster. E.g. the [workloads](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#-strong-workloads-apis-strong-).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes that is what I'm trying to do. I'm stuck at the authentication part. I somehow managed to get the authentication to work (I think) but when I make a request to the k8s API I get this error:
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "pods is forbidden: User \"clusterUser\" cannot list resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" at the cluster scope",
    "reason": "Forbidden",
    "details": {
        "kind": "pods"
    },
    "code": 403
}

I think this means the auth worked?

Comment: Yes, your auth worked, but your user does not have the necessary permissions. You need to create RBAC permissions for the user you use. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Comment: Aweesome thanks I'll try that. Seems a little odd to me though considering I was the one deploying the cluster in the first place.